# How do I create a topbottom window that is never covered by other topbottom windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, x11, electron

I want to have *n* (for now only two, but I will need more) mostbottom windows but preventing them to be covered by other mostbottom windows which were created before.

So, let's suppose we have 3 windows like this, created in this order:

- A
- B
- C

`A` will cannot cover `B` or `C`. `B` will cover only `A`, but not `C`. `C` will cover `A` and `B` and will *not* get covered by any of the previous created windows (`A` or `B`).

---

To create the windows I used [ElectronJS (former atom-shell)](https://github.com/atom/electron) and did the following:

```
var App = require('app')
  , BrowserWindow = require('browser-window')
  ;

var mainWindow = null;

...

App.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 100
      , height: 50
      , resizable: false
      , frame: false
      , type: "desktop"
    });
    mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/../index.html');
    ...
});
```

`type: "desktop"` will accomplish what I want, but only for one window. If I start another window like this (could be the same application, started twice, for example), they will be always on bottom, but the first window can cover the second window, which I don't want to happen (since `B` should not be covered by `A`).

Is it possible to do this under x11? I was looking at [`node-x11`](https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11) and I saw [there is a window property](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html) to set the desktop type (I wonder if Electron does the same or not): `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP`.

Or is there any other known solution for this case?

Comment: You may order the windows in your own application, but you can never define the order for windows of other applications. So, if the same application is started twice it may cover any other window, even if that is also the 'mosttop' window for that instance of the application. The exact policy is dictated by your window manager.

Comment: And oh, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP is not what you want. See http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html for an explanation of the available properties.

Comment: @JvO How should the window manager dictate that? Isn't this possible to be manipulated via x11?

Comment: The window manager (as it name implies) manages the windows for you; all you can give it are hints. Sure, you can use XRaiseWindow(), XLowerWindow() and XRestackWindows() but when it comes to edge cases as two 'topmost' windows competing for being the 'top', it is your window manager that decides who 'wins'. Anyway: I'm getting the impression this is an "XY question".... So exactly why do you need this particular window ordering (you may update your question to answer this).

Comment: @JvO Oh, *why* – in fact, I want to build a desktop shell and probably (if needed) a window manager on top of Electron. `:-D` Ok, full disclosure now.   In this case, I want to have an app for the wallpaper (which will be *always* on bottom) and some kind of desktop applets which are different apps but also on bottom, but not covered by the wallpaper app. :)

Comment: Ah.... Well, there is already an XWindow that is the desktop, it's called the root window. So you can just paint your wallpaper on the root window and that's it. The desktop is by definition below all other windows. See XRootWindow(); this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1248711 might be helpful too.

Comment: @JvO But I don't want that–at least for practice, I want to have a different app for that.

Comment: [What if two programs did this?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)